# Unable to connect to Locator via GFSH

Tags: spring-boot, gemfile, spring-data-gemfire, geode, gfsh

I have started a GemFire Server and Locator via *Spring Boot* and when I try to connect to the Locator from GFSH, I getting the following issue:

```
gfsh> connect
Connecting to Locator at [host=localhost, port=10334] ..
Connection refused: connect
```

Below, is the Spring (Java) configuration:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan 
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackages= "com.gemfire.demo") 
@CacheServerApplication(locators = "localhost[10334]") 
@EnableManager 
public class GemfireConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Properties gemfireProperties() {
        Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();
        gemfireProperties.setProperty("name", "SpringDataGemFireApplication");
        gemfireProperties.setProperty("mcast-port", "0");
        gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", "info");
        return gemfireProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache() {
        CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new CacheFactoryBean();
        gemfireCache.setClose(true);
        gemfireCache.setProperties(gemfireProperties());
        return gemfireCache;
    }

    @Bean(name="employee")
    @Autowired
    LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> getEmployee(final GemFireCache cache) {
        LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> employeeRegion = new LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee>();
        employeeRegion.setCache(cache);
        employeeRegion.setClose(false);
        employeeRegion.setName("employee");
        employeeRegion.setPersistent(false);
        employeeRegion.setDataPolicy(DataPolicy.PRELOADED);
        return employeeRegion;
    }
}
```

Ref:[Spring Data Gemfire locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099782/spring-data-gemfire-locator/31165400#comment94816055_31165400)
as per John's advice, I have enabled the Manager though I am still unable to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to connect to the *Locator* (using *Gfsh*) because you don't have a *Locator* (service, either standalone or embedded) running with just the *Spring* (Java) config shown above.

Note that the `@CacheServerApplication(locators = "localhost[10334]")` annotation, specifically with the `locators` attribute as you have configured above, does NOT start an embedded *Locator*.  It simply allows this *Spring Boot* configured and bootstrapped Apache Geode or Pivotal GemFire peer `Cache` node to join an existing distributed system (cluster) with an "existing" *Locator* running on `localhost`, listening on port `10334`.

For instance, you could have started a *Locator* using *Gfsh* (e.g. `start locator --name=X ...`), then started your *Spring Boot* application with the *Spring* (Java) config shown above and you would see the *Spring Boot* app as part of the cluster formed by the *Gfsh* started *Locator*.

It is simply a shortcut (convenience) to configure and start an "embedded" Locator, but to do so, you need to use the `@EnableLocator` annotation.

Therefore, to configure and start an (embedded) *Locator* service in the same *Spring Boot* application as the *CacheServer* (and *Manager*), you must also include the `@EnableLocator` annotation, like so:

```
@SpringBootApplicaton
@CacheServerApplication
@EnableLocator
@EnableManager(start = true)
public class GemFireServerApplication {

  ...
}
```

I have plenty of examples of this [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application), for instance [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/server/GeodeServerApplication.java#L74-L75), and talk about this generally [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#geode-cluster-configuration-bootstrapping), etc.

As a side note, your whole configuration (class) is confused and it is clear you don't quite understand what you are doing.  For instance, declaring the `gemfireProperties` and `gemfireCache` beans in JavaConfig is redundant and unnecessary since you are using the `@CacheServerApplication` annotation.  Your whole configuration could be simplified to:

@CacheServerApplication(
  name = "SpringDataGemFireApplication",
  locators = "localhost[10334]",
  logLevel = "info"
)
@EnableLocator
@EnableManager(start = true) 
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackages= "com.gemfire.demo") 
@ComponentScan
public class GemfireConfiguration {

```
@Bean(name="employee")
LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> getEmployee(GemFireCache cache) {

    LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> employeeRegion = 
        new LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee>();

    employeeRegion.setCache(cache);
    employeeRegion.setClose(false);
    employeeRegion.setName("employee");
    employeeRegion.setPersistent(false);
    employeeRegion.setDataPolicy(DataPolicy.PRELOADED);

    return employeeRegion;
}
```

}

Two things:

1) First, I would be highly careful about using classpath component scanning (`@ComponentScan`).  I am not a fan of this configuration approach, especially in production where things should be explicit.

2) I would encourage your to considering using the type-safe `basePackageClasses` attribute on the `@EnableGemFireRepositorities` annotation rather than the `basePackages` attribute.  With `basePackageClasses`, you only need to refer to a single interface/class in the desired package (e.g. `com.gemfire.demo`) rather than every interface/class.  The referenced interface/class serves as a pointer to identify the package to scan from, including all sub-packages.  It is type-safe and when your interfaces/classes in that package are re-located, then your attribute is still valid after the refactoring.

Anyway...

Hope this helps.

-j

Comment: even i tried with `@EnableLocator` also , but i am unable to make it

Comment: Then you possibly have another Exception occurring with an error message that should reveal the problem.  You need to make sure you are using the right version of _Gfsh_ that matches the version of _GemFire_ that SDG (or SBDG) is pulling in for you.  For instance, see here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix).  Unfortunately, this is a GemFire limitation.

Comment: now i can connect gfsh ,after downgraded my `GFSH` version to `9.5.2` .