# Configuring Pulse Data Browser in Spring Data GemFire 1.7.6.RELEASE

Tags: configuration, spring-data, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to get the Pulse data browser set up within our project, but having no luck. I  have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099782/spring-data-gemfire-locator) where John lays out pretty clear and concise instructions (from what I can tell it's still relevant) but I'm having issues troubleshooting. The version we are using is 1.7.6. Anyone have any suggestions as to what I can check out?

Below is the properties before I took a look at the repo. I saw in recent documentation that "jmx-manager-http-port" is deprecated but I'm unsure if that's the case with 1.7.6.RELEASE

```
<util:properties id="gemfire-props">
<prop key="log-level">warning</prop>
<prop key="mcast-port">0</prop>
<prop key="jmx-manager-start">true</prop>
<prop key="jmx-manager">true</prop>
<prop key="jmx-manager-http-port">8070</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Changed to this. I am able to connect to the locators and managers through GFSH no problem, have tried a couple of different ports and still able to connect to the new ones. I am never able to access localhost:[PORT]/pulse however.

```
<util:properties id="gemfire-props">
    <prop key="mcast-port">0</prop>
    <prop key="locators">localhost[11235]</prop>
    <prop key="log-level">warning</prop>
    <prop key="http-service-port">7070</prop>
    <prop key="jmx-manager">true</prop>
    <prop key="jmx-manager-port">1099</prop>
    <prop key="jmx-manager-start">true</prop>
    <prop key="start-locator">localhost[11235]</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Can post more config/information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

See the instructions in the ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** (and VMware Tanzu GemFire), SBDG, reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/index.html#geode-manager-applications):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/index.html#geode-manager-applications

Scroll down to the section, "***Additional, optional Manager depdendencies expressed in Gradle***".

The Apache Geode (VMware Tanzu GemFire, formerly Pivotal GemFire) Pulse application is a Web application that can either be bootstrapped in a standalone Servlet container such as Tomcat, or bootstrapped as part of the Geode/GemFire server JVM process, which configures and bootstraps an embedded Servlet container (currently, Eclipse Jetty).

When the `org.apache.geode:geode-pulse` dependency is on your Spring configured/bootstrapped Geode/GemFire server JVM process, and the Manager is enabled, it will locate the Pulse application classes and bootstrap Pulse inside the embedded Geode/GemFire Jetty Servlet container.

You can see more information in the ***Spring Data for Apache Geode*** (GemFire), SDG, reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-embedded-services) as well:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-embedded-services

A few housekeeping items:

1. SDG 1.x has been EOL for sometime.  In fact SDG, 2.2.x and older is EOL already. SDG 2.5.4 is the latest version, based on Apache Geode 1.13.x.  SDG 2.6 is already in development.  SDG 3.0 will be coming next year (2022) when Spring Framework 6 is available.  The baseline of SD[G] will be Spring Framework 6 and most likely Java 11, maybe even Java 17.  Currently, SDG is based on Spring Framework 5 and Java 8, FYI.
2. SDG 2.3.x is the last official version with VMware Tanzu GemFire dependencies/support (`spring-data-gemfire` module (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/tree/2.3.x)) in the `spring-data-geode` GitHub [repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode)).
3. This generally should not be a problem since [VMware Tanzu GemFire](https://tanzu.vmware.com/gemfire) is based on, and effectively is, the commercial version of [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/).
4. However, GemFire 9.10.9 is the latest release (see [here](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/gemfire/release_notes.html)) and is based on Apache Geode 1.12.4.  As of SDG 2.4, SDG is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.4.x/spring-data-geode/pom.xml#L23) Apache Geode 1.13.x, which means GemFire is no longer officially compatible at that version and therefore, cannot be included with SDG until a version of GemFire is based on Apache Geode 1.13.  I have no idea whether this will ever happen.
5. Finally, Spring for Geode/GemFire has grown significantly since the SDG 1.x days.  Since then, I have created the ***Spring Session for Apache Geode*** (SSDG) [project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode#spring-session-for-apache-geode--vmware-tanzu-gemfire), ***Spring Test for Apache Geode*** (STDG) [project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-data-geode#spring-test-framework-for-apache-geode--vmware-tanzu-gemfire), and Spring Boot for Apache Geode (SBDG) [project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode#spring-boot-for-apache-geode).  In all of Spring, we encourage users to start with Spring Boot first, and that is no different for Apache Geode and VMware Tanzu GemFire.  In fact, you can even start projects using Apache Geode on [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.5.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=geode).  SBDG really is the best way to get started with Apache Geode or GemFire.  See the [guided tour](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/data/tanzu-gemfire/guides/spring-for-apache-geode/) for more details.

Please post in the comments if you have more questions.